# Need your help, full of signal BUY or SELL

Tags: pine-script

I have a problem with my indicator in v5.

I would like to have just 1 signal of BUY or SELL when the conditions are good. Not a lot like on the picture.

Do you know how to do it?

```
    //@version=5
indicator(title='Bot 1 Indicateurs BUY / SELL', shorttitle='Bot 1 Indicateurs BUY / SELL', overlay=true)
UseHAcandles = input(true, title='Use Heikin Ashi Candles in Algo Calculations')
//
// === INPUTS ===


AlerteBuy = input('voir buy')
AlerteSell = input('voir buy')

// === BASE FUNCTIONS ===

haClose = UseHAcandles ? request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, close) : close
haOpen = UseHAcandles ? request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, open) : open
haHigh = UseHAcandles ? request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, high) : high
haLow = UseHAcandles ? request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, low) : low



long = haClose > haHigh[1] and haClose > haOpen and haHigh[1] > haHigh[2] and close > high[3]
short = haClose < haOpen and haClose < haLow[1]




alertcondition(condition=long, title='Buy Signal', message='Short TP Hit @ ${{plot("Short TP")}}')


alertcondition(condition=short, title='Sell Signal', message='Short TP Hit @ ${{plot("Short TP")}}')


plotshape(long, title='plotbuy', style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.blue, 0), size=size.tiny, title='buy label', text='BUY ↗️', textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0) )
plotshape(short, title='plotsell', style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.red, 0), size=size.tiny, title='sell label', text='SELL ↘️', textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0) )
```

[My Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFoxK.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it to show buy signal once until a sell signal occurs, and to show sell signal only once until a buy signal occurs. You can do this by saving what signal occured, in a variable. Then check it while generating long and short signal. Like below

```
//@version=5
indicator(title='Bot 1 Indicateurs BUY / SELL', shorttitle='Bot 1 Indicateurs BUY / SELL', overlay=true)
UseHAcandles = input(true, title='Use Heikin Ashi Candles in Algo Calculations')
//
// === INPUTS ===


AlerteBuy = input('voir buy')
AlerteSell = input('voir buy')

// === BASE FUNCTIONS ===

haClose = UseHAcandles ? request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, close) : close
haOpen = UseHAcandles ? request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, open) : open
haHigh = UseHAcandles ? request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, high) : high
haLow = UseHAcandles ? request.security(ticker.heikinashi(syminfo.tickerid), timeframe.period, low) : low


var lastsignal=0

long = haClose > haHigh[1] and haClose > haOpen and haHigh[1] > haHigh[2] and close > high[3] and  lastsignal<1
short = haClose < haOpen and haClose < haLow[1] and   lastsignal>-1
if long 
    lastsignal:=1
if short
    lastsignal:=-1
 



alertcondition(condition=long, title='Buy Signal', message='Short TP Hit @ ${{plot("Short TP")}}')


alertcondition(condition=short, title='Sell Signal', message='Short TP Hit @ ${{plot("Short TP")}}')


plotshape(long, title='plotbuy', style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.blue, 0), size=size.tiny, title='buy label', text='BUY ↗️', textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0) )
plotshape(short, title='plotsell', style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(color.red, 0), size=size.tiny, title='sell label', text='SELL ↘️', textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0) )
```

[image]